# get all and remove all value from redis using RedisTemplate zSet using wildchar

Tags: java, redis

How to get all and remove all value from redis using RedisTemplate zSet values from wildchar key in Java for removeRangeByScore and  reverseRangeByScore operation

I am trying with * concatenation but its not working.

```
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().removeRangeByScore(empId + "*", Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE)
```

To Find

```
redisTemplate.opsForZSet().reverseRangeByScore(empId + "*", Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get first the set of keys:

```
Set<String> keys = redisTemplate.keys(empId + "*");
```

Then you need to loop:

```
for (String key : keys) {
    redisTemplate.del(key);
}
```

Note that removing all values from a zSet is the same that deleting the zSet. Empty sets are deleted by Redis. That's why I use `del` above.

To get all values in reverse order by score, make sure to use `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` and  `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`, as these would translate to `-inf` and `+inf` in Redis. You also need to loop through all keys here.